# Issue with Godaddy DNS manager

Tags: domains, dns, email, spam, godaddy

I'm using [domains.live.com](http://domains.live.com) to setup an email to a domain registered on [Godaddy](http://Godaddy.com).  The domains.live.com configuration page says:

[image]

Godaddy's DNS manager isn't accepting this string `Value: v=spf1 include:hotmail.com ~all` it gives an error, something is wrong, either with the string or with the DNS manager and I would like to know how to fix it.

---

***Notes***: *The more information link is dead, Godaddy no longer gives support by email, no Microsoft support*

Comment: If you need GoDaddy support, call them. It has been my experience that their support does work well. Your tech may have to refer to another tech or two, or refer to a manual, but there is good support for the first line techs including getting a supervisor if necessary.

Comment: @closetnoc I might have to do so, the thing is international calls in my country are so expensive, so if I can the US and they hold for like 10 minutes in order to investigate the issue, it's going to cost a lot for such a silly issue :)

Comment: I kinda assumed that was why you were asking. I only wish I had an answer for you to save you the trouble. Perhaps it will pay off to wait a while. They also have a chat option on their support page on the right side toward the bottom. That may help!

Comment: @closetnoc yes I wil try that

Comment: Let me know how it goes and what the answer is. You can answer your own question after 8 hours by the way.

Comment: Does this [KB Article](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names) help??

Comment: @ECarterYoung issue solved by the answer below

Comment: @closetnoc issue solved by the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it; the text of the record should only be what follows "Value:"

```
v=spf1 include:hotmail.com ~all
```

See the [syntax documentation](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#include) on the OpenSPF website.

In the new DNS manager interface, just add a TXT record like so:

[image: Screenshot from GoDaddy DNS Manager]

In the old DNS Manager, when you add a TXT record you will see the following:

*Note: Using TXT records for SPF information is being replaced by the SPF record, itself.*

In this case, you can use GoDaddy's SPF generator, filling in the details as options on a tabbed interface.

If you simply "Quick Add" a TXT record, you can do it with basically just the value from above.

[image: Quick Add DNS TXT Record]

Comment: Oh I don't believe I didn't notice that